# Select parent which contains a child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to create a CSS selector, which selects the `div.outer` element, which contains `div.good-inner`? Example:

```
<div class="outer">
    <!-- this is good -->
    <div class="good-inner">This gets selected!</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <!-- has `outer` as class, but doesn't have `good-inner` inside of it -->
    <div class="bad-inner">This doesn't.</div>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- has `good-inner`, but doesn't possess `outer` as class --> 
    <div class="good-inner">Neither does this.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. No parent or ancestor selector yet

Comment: That is only possible with [`:has()` in CSS Selectors level 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), which isn't implemented in any browsers yet.